# Use FluentValidation with custom properties in a c# winform application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, fluentvalidation

I am currently developing an application, linked to a database, but it doesn't use EntityFramework to generate the database objects. Instead I've created custom classes that handle the entities. The fields within these entities use custom classes too. Here is a quick example:

```cs
public class BookEntity : Entity
{
    public Field BookId {get; set;}
    public Field Name {get; set;}
    public Field Page {get; set;}

    public BookEntity()
    {
        BookId = new Field("Books_BookId");
        Name = new Field("Books_Name");
        Page = new Field("Books_Page");
    }
}

public class Field
{
    public String Viewfield{get; set;}
    public Object Value{get; set;}
}
```

As you can see, my `Field` class contains two properties. The first one contains  the name of the field (With the Tablename) and the other one is the value.

My issue is that using FluentValidation, I would like to be able to set the returned property name to my `Viewfield` property. I am currently able to do this using the `WithState` extensions, however I would need to specify it at every fluent validation rule.

```cs
private class BookValidator : AbstractValidator<Book>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor that contains all the validation rules
    /// </summary>
    public BookValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(p => (Double?)p.Page.Value)
            .NotNull().WithState(p => p.Page.Viewfield)
            .LessThanOrEqualTo(p => 1000).WithState(p => p.Page.Viewfield)
            .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(p =>100).WithState(p => p.Page.Viewfield)
    }
}
```

I did try to do it with the `PropertyNameResolver`, but since I cannot access the instance of Book while in the resolver, I cannot access the `Viewfield` property.

**What I would like to have is something that could avoid the repetition of WithState.**

Also, note that I cannot use Custom Attributes on my field to set the `Viewfield`.

I hope I did well explained myself,

Thanks.

Comment: This just seems like an overly complicated way to not use an ORM...

Comment: Why you simply didn't use `public int BookId {get; set;}`? and the same for other properties.

Comment: I would like to be able to do that, even migrate the framework to EntityFramework, but I currently cannot. As @DavidG said, this is an overly complicated way to not use an ORM, but I have to work with this for now..

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you have this odd `Field` class?

Comment: This `Field` class contains a lot more information than the one I put in my example. Since the framework is currently running, I do not have the time and do not want to break anything for now. I know this seems odd, but I do have to work with this. For now, I do duplicate the `.WithState` function, but I just want to know if anybody would have an easier way to do this using FluentValidation and the current class schema that I have.

Comment: @Yannick Off-Topic but you can think about using attributes like `[DisplayName]` to have meta data about your fields and keep your models clean.

Comment: Yes that true. I did try that by setting the display name to the `Viewfield` value, but we do have some entities that implement an interface (Yes, that's even more odd!) and sometimes, we use this interface in FluentValidation instead of the class itself. 

Therefore if I try to use the `DisplayName[]` attribute when FluentValidation use the interface, I cannot retrieve the attribute value (Because I am from an interface).

Thanks however for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know FluentValidation but i think that your implementation is really too odd to be supported, maybe FluentValidation has some kind of pluggable mechanism to get the property value that you can hook, but i doubt... anyway odd for odd (btw that's really odd :D), you could wrap all FluentAPI into your own Extension, like NotNullEx,  LessThanOrEqualToEx, etc...

those extensions has just to take one parameter more respect the correspondent FluentAPI , then into that extensions you call the FluentValidation validator and return its result so you can chain and keep the syntax fluent

e.g.

```
RuleFor(p => (Double?)p.Page.Value)
        .NotNull().WithState(p => p.Page.Viewfield)
```

could become

```
RuleFor(p => (Double?)p.Page.Value)
        .NotNullEx(p => p.Page.Viewfield)
```

this doesn't help you much tho because you need anyway to specify that linq selector (or straight parameter value if you let the extension accept a string to select the property name)

the other way is to create your own validators that inherit from the original one and hook them to the FluentValidator, either way you should anyway pass that property value, so i don't think it would be the perfect solution anyway

Update:
reading the WithState extension here https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/blob/c101786a923406acff6029b00f664a91a097a9af/src/FluentValidation/DefaultValidatorOptions.cs it seems to me that you could just call WithState after RuleFor(...) and not for every validation line

so instead of

```
RuleFor(p => (Double?)p.Page.Value)
   .NotNull().WithState(p => p.Page.Viewfield)
   .LessThanOrEqualTo(p => 1000).WithState(p => p.Page.Viewfield)
   .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(p =>100).WithState(p => p.Page.Viewfield)
```

you could try with

```
RuleFor(p => (Double?)p.Page.Value)
   .NotNull()
   .WithState(p => p.Page.Viewfield)
   .LessThanOrEqualTo(p => 1000)
   .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(p =>100)
```

does this works?

Comment: Yes, I think that my current framework just isn't well made to support the FluentValidation framework. I did try to do the extension, but I would have to override the entire validation process of FluentValidation to keep my custom value until the ValidationResult is returned. While it could work, it is way more complicated than duplicating the `.WithState` line on every validation rule step. (Thanks for the help though! :D)

Comment: are you sure you need to specify WithState for every kind of validation on a single field?
it seems to me, reading the WithState extension here https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/blob/c101786a923406acff6029b00f664a91a097a9af/src/FluentValidation/DefaultValidatorOptions.cs that you could just call it after RuleFor(...)

Comment: I am unable to call it after RuleFor because WithState is an extensions of `IRuleBuilderOptions` while RuleFor return a `IRuleBuilderInitial`

I did try to create my own WithState extension using the `IRuleBuilderInitial` and it did work. However, while setting the configuration, it gave me an error because the configuration wasn't yet created (ORNS).

Comment: and only after the first validation?
probably it is an unwanted feature but could work, because internally it call the rule.Configure and i think this keep settings all the time the same propertyname, could worth a try, see updated answer

Comment: I did try that too. It didn't work since the second validation overrides the first one. 
For example (using your updated code), if my value is null, my State will be `p.Page.Viewfield` which is good, however if my value is 23 the State will be null.